# Why there are so many cc1.exe task running whenever I open my Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cpu-usage, taskmanager

I am experiencing this problem since a long time. Whenever I open my Visual Studio Code IDE, my laptop starts hanging and after opening the task manager, I can see a lot of `cc1.exe` tasks running with **CPU usage 100%**. Also I am unable to run my code as the terminal get stuck!

**Here is the screenshot of the problem**

[image: Screenshot of the tasks]

I had searched the Internet for this problem but didn't find anything about it as if it is happening to me only :-(

I don't know what are they and from where they started. I manually end them using "End Task".

This is very frustrating. Is this a problem of VS Code??

Comment: How many cores does you CPU has? Usually build tools uses all the cores available + 1, for compilation.

Comment: @marcinj 4 cores

Comment: If you are seeing these process when you are not running a build command, then very likely these are processes spawned in the background to index the project by Visual Studio. This help VS with IntelliSense. There might be some tuning parameters for this, will have to check documentation.

Comment: @Anirudh yes you are right. I didn't performed any build command, then also just after opening VS Code these processes started immediately. Although this happens 2/10 times but then also. Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it is very frustating.